# api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll missing when d3dcompiler_47.dll is redistributed

Tags: c++, windows, directx

As per instruction from the Windows 8.1 DirectX SDK, d3dcompiler_47.dll is to be redistributed with any Direct3D program from now on.  When I try and run my program on a Windows 7 machine with this dll in the same folder, I get a "api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll missing" error.  A quick google search suggests this is because of a version mix-up somewhere - is d3dcompiler_47.dll incompatible with this machine?  I've checked to make sure it has DirectX 11 installed, which is the version of DirectX that I'm using, and can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: `d3dcompiler_47.dll is to be redistributed with any Direct3D program from now on` What? Where did you see this? MS is heavily discouraging of using D3DCompiler stuff at all. It's recommended to use offline compilation instead.

Comment: @Drop ["With the Windows 8.0 SDK, the D3DCompile DLL is never installed to the %WINDIR% folders. Instead, you should copy it into your applications folder and deploy it 'application local' with your Win32 desktop application."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. A quote from your link: As we have recommended for many years, developers should compile their HLSL shaders at build-time rather than rely on runtime compilation.

Comment: @Drop This is for an editor, which allows low-level HLSL programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can only go wrong if you copied d3dcompiler_47.dll from your Windows directory.  Which is not suitable to run on older Windows versions.

You *must* use the redistributable version of it.  You'll find it back in the Windows SDK directory.  Like C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Redist\D3D on most machines.  Pick the x86 or the x64 version of it, depending on the platform target you used to compile your program.

Comment: Well, that would be it then.  I just searched and copied the first result.