# d3dcompiler_47.dll, ILMerge failing. Also wont add to GAC. Any Idea?

Tags: c#, dll, gac, ilmerge

Goal: I need all the files in my bin to be grouped into a single dll. or added to the GAC

I am using CefSharp To run chromium in a windows form.
We are using some software that will only allow me to add one dll (no other files).

I have access to the GAC on all machines. And I have been using ILMerge to attempt to bundle the files with the dll.

I have been able to get all the files to bundle except for.  d3dcompiler_47.dll

When I try to add to GAC it tells me it has a bad manfiest.
When I try to bundle d3dcompiler_47.dll with my dll, it says

> "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'd3dcompiler_47.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was
>   expected to contain an assembly manifest. File name:
>   'd3dcompiler_47.dll' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'd3dcompiler_47.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. File name:
>   'd3dcompiler_47.dll'"

(I have reviewed this but found that its 2 versions of d3d... do not work with  CefSharp)
 [api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll missing when d3dcompiler_47.dll is redistributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546453/api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0-dll-missing-when-d3dcompiler-47-dll-is-redi/24548796#24548796)

Is there anyway to add d3dcompiler_47 (from CefSharp) to bundle or be added to the GAC?

Comment: d3dcompiler_47.dll is a purely unmanaged DLL, it cannot be merged and cannot be added to the GAC.  Use the common way to merge executable files, surely you've used Setup.exe before.  Also useful to avoid deploying this DLL when the machine already has it.

Comment: I am unable to use the common way, with Encompass360 The Program that allows me to give it a single dll for a form. But Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans said, you can't use ILMerge for unmanaged dlls.

Fody [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) however should work, at least it says so in its features.